# How to restrict users to a tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an app that i want to restrict users from clicking on the'REGISTER' tab as below.
How do I do that. the users will have 3 types of users,

```
User
Admin
SuperUser
```

we want to restrict the "regiser" tab to Superusers only.

```
<dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="hlRegister" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" Text="Register" NavigateUrl="javascript:LoadChildWindow('Views/Register.aspx', 'Register');"></dx:ASPxHyperLink>
<dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="hlHome" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" Text="Home" NavigateUrl="javascript:LoadChildWindow('Views/Center.aspx');"></dx:ASPxHyperLink>
<dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="hlLogout" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" Text="Logout" NavigateUrl="javascript:btnLogout.DoClick();"></dx:ASPxHyperLink>
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnLogout" ClientInstanceName="btnLogout" ClientVisible="false" runat="server" OnClick="ASPxButton1_Click"></dx:ASPxButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not specify the ASPxHyperLink.NavigateUrl property and the left click will not be available.

If a user doens't have the rights try the following in the code behind

```
hlRegister.NavigateUrl = null;
```

Not tested just assuming

Comment: OK thanks there Tsukasa, but if I want only certain users those who have SuperUser their status? they can navigate all others no. We have col User_Type on the user table, 1 would be the Super User that can navigate the Register tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   User myuser=GetMyUser();//load from your database or whatever
   if(myuser.Role==Roles.SuperUser)
   {
      //don't set the NavigateURL link as @TSukasa suggested, or disable the control.
   }
}
```